# SharePoint Message after Saving Record on Custom Editform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom editform.aspx where I actually stay on the page after a save action but I need to show a message that states that the record has been saved. is this possible?

Comment: Can you share script/code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but you could use Sharepoint Designer to send an email to the 'created by' person.

I don't know if you've used Designer already, but it is for free and can be downloaded [here is a link for Designer 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35491) (I use this, since I am using Sharepoint 2013).

If you need me to post a screenshot of how the code looks in Designer, let me know.

Comment: not really what I was looking for but thanks...   System already sends out emails, I am just looking to post a message to the screen that indicates the record has been saved

Comment: then probably either jquery or javascript would do this, but I'm an absolute beginner...someone else would be able to help.  It would need some custom coding.  [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp) might get you started...(I just found it by Googling it), but it is probably a bit hardcore to learn!  For a quicker result search google and find someone else that's done the same thing.  You'll probably find something on this site too - [have a look here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+pop-up+box)